# iOS Animation não fixa no ponto final quando usado dentro de um UITextField no didBegin

Tags: ios, objective-c

Quero que quando o usuário entre em um campo `UITextField`, faça uma animação simples de mover um `UIView` para baixo, por exemplo.

Se eu colocar a minha rotina Up Inside funciona, a mesma rotina no `didBegin` do `UItextfield` não funciona, ele anima para baixo e quando chega no ponto definido ele volta para o lugar de partida.

PS: uso a mesma rotina nos dois casos.

Alguém tem alguma ideia do que possa estar errado?

Rotina:

```
-(IBAction)testa:(id)sender {
    CGPoint fromPt = self.viewStatus.layer.position;
    CGPoint toPt = CGPointMake(fromPt.x, fromPt.y+200);

    CABasicAnimation* anime = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position"];
    anime.delegate = self;
    anime.removedOnCompletion = NO;
    anime.duration = 2;
    anime.fromValue = [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:fromPt];
    anime.toValue = [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:toPt];
    CAMediaTimingFunction* tf = [CAMediaTimingFunction
                                 functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseOut];
    anime.timingFunction = tf;
    [self.viewStatus.layer addAnimation:anime forKey:@"ResizeForKeyboard"];

    self.viewStatus.frame = CGRectMake(self.viewStatus.frame.origin.x,
                                       toPt.y,
                                       self.viewStatus.frame.size.width,
                                       self.viewStatus.frame.size.height);
}
```

Comment: compartilhei uma pasta com o projeto que eu fiz pra testar. Basta descompassar o zip.  https://www.dropbox.com/s/mj4ceg6v2uo7vaz/teste.zip?dl=0

Answer (score 1):

Boa tarde Moacir,
Eu já utilizei animações na mesma situação que a sua. Resolvi da seguinte maneira:

```
-(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField{
            [UIView animateWithDuration:2.0 delay:0
                                options:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut
                             animations:^{
                                 [viewStatus setFrame: CGRectMake(fromPt.x, fromPt.y+200, viewComponents.frame.size.width, viewComponents.frame.size.height)];
                             }completion:nil];
        }
    }
```